# Convert a 2D array of numbers which represent item types into an image using PIL

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a 2D array full of numbers which represent specific item types in a program I'm making. So 0 = empty space, 1 = wall, 2 = box, 3 = destination and 4 = player.

So is there a way to convert this 2D array into an image in python (maybe with PIL) where each number represents a different emoji.

The 2D array:

```py
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is.  How would it know which emoji to use for each number?

Comment: I don't know, thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so the first step is to turn this 2D array (we'll call it `mat`) into an array of emojis instead of numbers. Let's start by declaring our number-to-emoji mapping:

```py
EMOJI_MAP = {
    0: " ",
    1: "",
    2: "",
    3: "⭕️",
    4: ""
}
```

Then, we can use list comprehensions to convert the whole map from numbers to emojis:

```py
mat = [[EMOJI_MAP[x] for x in arr] for arr in mat]
```

Now, let's draw our image with PIL. We need to use a font that supports emojis -- I'm using [Noto Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye) here.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Create image
out = Image.new("RGB", (540, 230), (255, 255, 255))

# Get drawing context
d = ImageDraw.Draw(out)

# Import font
font = ImageFont.truetype("./NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf", 14)

# Draw text based on mat, starting at (10,10), with the emoji font
# Newlines used to separate rows of mat, spaces used for columns
d.multiline_text((10,10), "\n".join([" ".join(x) for x in mat]), fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font)
```

Run `out.show()` to see the image, and you'll see something like this!
[image: Final result of code]